# How to setup @ConfigurationProperties to get the values from Hashicorp Vault what is at the address secret/demo-app/keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-vault

I started a Hashicorp Vault and my secrets can be found at `secret/demo-app/keycloak`. I have 2 values here: `clientId`, `clientSecret`

I setup the `bootstrap.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=demo-app
spring.cloud.vault.token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
```

But I did not find a way to make some `@Data` and `@Configuration` classes that can read these values at startup using `@ConfigurableProperties`:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("keycloak")
public class Client {
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("PostConstruct: " + this.toString());
    }
}
```

But does not seem to work:

`PostConstruct: Client(clientId=null, clientSecret=null)`

Any ideas what did I miss? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my working solution.
I have one secret in vault, which is key=secret, values=.
Please notice setters and getters should be defined accordingly.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("mysecret")
public class MySecret {
    private String secret;
    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }
    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }
}
```

Now to use it in any service class, we can use @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation , and just autowire it.

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MySecret.class)
class my ClientService {

@autowire private MySecret mySecret;
}
```

it works for me.